# bash: alias: Added by Anaconda2 5.3.0 Installer appears on terminal

Tags: bash, anaconda, alias

[image]

This image appears every time I load up the terminal after installing Anaconda2 5.3.0 for Mac.

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an error on the part of the Anaconda installer, as they added unnecessary information to the bash_profile. To fix this issue, open your bash profile (on Mac, run the command `open ~/.bash_profile` from user's base directory i.e. /Users/[your-username]).

At the bottom of the file, you will see where the Anaconda installer added the following text:

"# added by Anaconda2 5.3.0 installer"

Delete that, and you will be good to go! The message will no longer appear the next time you open a terminal.

[image]

Comment: It's still an open question what's causing that to be executed as a command rather than properly treated as a comment -- if you run that command in a regular terminal, you'll see none of the "not found" errors. If you wanted to track it down, consider `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i`, logging next to each command run the specific source file and line number that triggered it.

Comment: (well, none of the errors unless maybe the space before the `#` is a non-breaking space rather than a real hex-20 ASCII space character; I suppose that's plausible, but we can't tell that from a screenshot -- which is part of why [we discourage posting images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)).